# What's the best kind of caulk that doesn't dry out or become tacky enough to gather dirt?

Tags: caulking, caulk

I've used various caulks but have never found the magical one that neither dries out nor becomes sticky and tacky enough to attract dirt and dust. I know this stuff exists because all the caulked joints at a friend's house have this stuff, and it's amazing. It never dries out, but isn't tacky or sticky, so it isn't a dirt magnet. It's glassy smooth, yet pliable.

Anyone have an idea what this stuff is?

Comment: By 'dried out' do you mean becomes hard? Are you *sure* you were using caulk and not adhesive? Or perhaps adhesive caulk? Nearly every caulk I've ever used stays both soft and is never tacky when dry.

Comment: I don't think so. I've used paintable acrylic caulk, siliconized acrylic caulk, silicone caulk, and some kind of "anti-microbial" kitchen and bathroom caulk. None of them were glue-type stuff

Comment: Huh. I've never had issues with those caulks. When you apply, do you smooth the bead out with a wet finger? That will help get a smooth finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first look inside yourself, Grasshopper.

When is the time that which is still soft no longer welcomes the new into its grasp.

Come to me when you have the answer, and we will find peace within you.

Others have found the answer in GE Silicone II or similar.

Look to the  enormous orange beast to find samples on those backed with cardstock.

All in a family are similar. Yet families have the great range in size and color.

Seek, and you will find that which can satisfy your emptiness.

Comment: GE Silicone II it was.